# How to connect textbox with parameter?

Tags: c#

I have two classes: `FormOne` and `123`.

In `FormOne`, there are textboxes, labels and buttons code. In `123` there are connecting with Erply database, and I have to make login form where clients can log in so I have to connect textbox with username, so if the client wants to log in, then the program sends the information to Erply and sends back if the username and password are correct.

So shortly how to connect parameter "username" with textbox?

```
class FormOne
{
    private void textBox18_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //username textbox
        //I need code in here
    }
}
class 123
{
    async public void DoItJustDoItPleaseIBegYou()
    {
        string erplyPilv = "http://**clientcode**.erply.com/api/";  //"http://***.***.***.**:****/**/"

        await VerifyUser(erplyPilv, "verifyUser", "request", "**username**", "**password**", "**clientcode**", "0.1");
    }

    public async Task VerifyUser(string url, string VerifyUser, string request, string username, string password, string clientcode, string version)
    {
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queries = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("request", VerifyUser),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("clientCode", clientcode),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("version", version),
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: `how to connect parameter "username" with textbox?`.. um you don't... Where and how are you calling `DoItJustDoItPleaseIBegYou`?

Comment: `async void` is a really bad idea.  Your method should at least be returning a `Task`.

Comment: @David You're not wrong but I think that's the least of OPs concerns right now.

Comment: @ChrisPickford I would agree, but it's always good if someone *could* point out potential issue's when they see them; there's nothing wrong with that :)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to pass the value from the textbox to your code in your other class

```
class FormOne
{
    private void textBox18_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        123 OtherClass = new 123( );
        123.DoItJustDoItPleaseIBegYou( textBox18.text );
    }
}
class 123
{
    async public void DoItJustDoItPleaseIBegYou(string UserName)
    {
        string erplyPilv = "http://**clientcode**.erply.com/api/";  //"http://***.***.***.**:****/**/"

        await VerifyUser( erplyPilv, "verifyUser", "request", UserName, "**password**", "**clientcode**", "0.1" );
    }

public async Task VerifyUser(string url, string VerifyUser, string request, string username, string password, string clientcode, string version)
{
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queries = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>( )
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("request", VerifyUser),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", username),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("clientCode", clientcode),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("version", version),
    };
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Assuming that your text box is called textBox18 (which it appears to be, based on the name of your function), then:

```
private void textBox18_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var userName = textBox18.Text;
}
```

Comment: The scope of that variable is only method, what if the OP isn't calling anything that uses this var? IMHO, it would be best to have a class level scope...

Comment: This answers the question.